# fusion consultas sql

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT Date(f.Fecha),SUM(f.Total) as fac FROM factura f WHERE 
    f.Tipo='Factura' AND f.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' GROUP BY 
    Date(f.Fecha);
    SELECT Date(s.Fecha),SUM(s.Total) as sal FROM sales s WHERE s.Fecha BETWEEN 
    '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' GROUP BY Date(s.Fecha);
    SELECT Date(a.Fecha),SUM(a.Abono) as abo FROM abonos a WHERE a.Fecha 
    BETWEEN '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' GROUP BY Date(a.Fecha);
```

COMO OBTENGO ESTOS 3 RESULTADOS EN UNA SOLA CONSULTA

```
fecha    tabla1 tabla2  tabla3  total
9/13/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/14/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/15/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/16/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/17/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/18/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/19/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/20/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/21/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/22/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
9/23/2018   xxx xxx xx  xx
```

algo asi espero recibir

Comment: Como hago para obtener esos 3 resultados en una sola consulta???

Comment: Probaste usando [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: si y no me sirvio

Comment: Ok, de que forma quieres obtener tus datos, porque el [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) se utiliza para unir un conjunto de resultados de dos o mas instrucciones como en este caso, en tus querys no veo nada que relacione tus tablas, por lo que la opción lógica es usar UNION

Comment: tengo 3 tablas lo que necesito es imprimir la fecha y los datos de esa fecha sumados si existen y si no existen mostrar 0  en un rango de fechas. Ejemplo obtener total de esas 3 tablas del dia 1 al dia 5.

Comment: algo asi: 

dia 1  0,1000,200
dia 2 67,87,90
dia 3 0,0,0
dia 4 1,2,4 
dia 5 0,0,0

Comment: pero en lugar de dia 1, dia2 ... la fecha

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente podrías resolverlo con un `UNION ALL` y una subconsulta. Con el `UNION ALL` unimos las tres consultas en un único recordset, debe ser `UNION ALL`, un `UNION` sencillo eliminaría eventuales filas duplicadas cosa que no queremos. Estos resultados serán una subconsulta que volveremos a agrupar por Fecha. Agregamos además una suma condicional para poder tener ademas los subtotales que componen el total general.

```
SELECT Fecha,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.Consulta = 1 THEN T.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Factura,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.Consulta = 2 THEN T.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.Consulta = 3 THEN T.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Abonos,
       SUM(T.Total)                                          AS Total
       FROM (
           SELECT 1 AS Consulta, Date(f.Fecha) as Fecha, SUM(f.Total) as Total
                  FROM factura f 
                  WHERE f.Tipo='Factura' AND f.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' 
                  GROUP BY Date(f.Fecha)

           UNION ALL

           SELECT 2, Date(s.Fecha), SUM(s.Total)
                  FROM sales s 
                  WHERE s.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' 
                  GROUP BY Date(s.Fecha)

           UNION ALL

           SELECT 3, Date(a.Fecha), SUM(a.Abono)
                  FROM abonos a 
                  WHERE a.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-20' AND '2018-09-25' 
                  GROUP BY Date(a.Fecha)
       ) T
       GROUP BY T.Fecha
       ORDER BY T.Fecha
```

Comment: Esta grandioso, funciona perfecto pero creo que no me explique bien pido disculpas. Lo que queria era obtener el total1, el total2,total3 y al final total de los totales como lo acabas de hacer. Si me puedes ayudar te lo agradezco

Comment: fecha tabla1 tabla2 tabla3 total
9/13/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/14/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/15/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/16/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/17/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/18/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/19/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/20/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/21/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/22/2018 xxx xxx xx xx
9/23/2018 xxx xxx xx xx

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez, te entiendo, verifica mi última edición. Te sugiero que elimines la respuesta que has dado y la agregues como edición a tu pregunta así queda todo consistente. Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias me salvaste la tanda. Sos un maestro mysql . Gracias otra vez